# C# use loop to check button clicks in Windows Form

Tags: c#

I'm creating a version of the game Qwixx in C# for a class project. I currently have buttons from P1R2 through P1R12 in a row going left to right. When the End Turn button is clicked, it disables any buttons that have a X or - instead of the number.

```
        private void P1R2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (P1R2Clicked == false)
        {
            P1R2.Text = "X";
            P1R2Clicked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            P1R2.Text = "2";
            P1R2Clicked = false;
        }
    }

    private void P1R3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (P1R3Clicked == false)
        {
            P1R3.Text = "X";
            if (P1R2.Text == "2")
            {
                P1R2.Text = "-";
            }
            P1R3Clicked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            P1R3.Text = "3";
            if (P1R2.Text == "-")
            {
                P1R2.Text = "2";
            }
            P1R3Clicked = false;
        }
    }

    private void P1R4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (P1R4Clicked == false)
        {
            P1R4.Text = "X";
            if (P1R3.Text == "3")
            {
                P1R3.Text = "-";
            }
            if (P1R2.Text == "2")
            {
                P1R2.Text = "-";
            }
            P1R4Clicked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            P1R4.Text = "4";
            if (P1R3.Text == "-")
            {
                P1R3.Text = "3";
            }
            if (P1R2.Text == "-")
            {
                P1R2.Text = "2";
            }
            P1R4Clicked = false;
        }
    }
```

With the code above, I'm making sure a user can click a button multiple times and changes the text on the buttons to the left if they're displaying the number. I'm trying to find a way to run these checks through a method in another class where I can iterate through a loop. The problem is I cannot find a way to check for a variable P1R#Clicked to push through a loop. Or how to run P1R#.Text through. Thoughts?

Edit:
[Red Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhvAo.png)

```
        private void P1Red_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var index = Array.IndexOf(P1RedButtons, sender);
        if (index == 10)
        {
            foreach (Button s in P1RRow.Controls.OfType<Button>())
            {
                if (s.Text == "X")
                {
                    P1NoRed++;
                }
            }
            P1RedButtons[index].Text = P1NoRed < 5 ? (index + 2).ToString() : "X";
            P1RedClicked[index] = P1NoRed < 5 ? !P1RedClicked[index] : P1RedClicked[index];
            P1RedX[index] = P1NoRed < 5 ? !P1RedX[index] : P1RedX[index];
            P1NoRed = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            P1RedButtons[index].Text = P1RedClicked[index] ? (index + 2).ToString() : "X";
        }
            if (index != 0)
            {
                if (P1RedClicked[index - 1] == false)
                {
                    int red1found = Array.LastIndexOf(P1RedX, true, index - 1);

                    for (int j = index - 1; j > red1found; j--)
                    {
                        P1RedButtons[j].Text = P1RedClicked[index] ? (j + 2).ToString() : "-";
                    }
                }
            }
        P1RedClicked[index] = !P1RedClicked[index];
        P1RedX[index] = !P1RedX[index];
    }
```

In this code, P1NoRed is a counter to check if at least 5 buttons have been clicked and have a "X" on them. It won't allow the number 12 to be clicked until there are 5 other "X"s in the row. Everything is working at this time, including putting "-"s to the left of a clicked number and undoing it if clicked again. The End Turn button locks these buttons and disables any with a "X" or "-". I'm currently working on finding a way to track the number of buttons clicked in a turn before the End Turn button is pressed. Per the rules of the game, 2 buttons can be clicked on your turn, 1 button if it's not your turn. I know I need a counter somewhere in the event, possibly scanning the P1RedClicked array for true values. My thought is when the second x is clicked to disable any button from the furthest right "X" on the row to the left end. I'd be open to suggestions as I'm working on it. Thank you very much @Enigmativity for all of the help so far.

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your logic in your code above. Can you please clarify your logic?

Comment: P1R2 needs to change text from X to 2 if clicked. The End Turn button disables any buttons with X for the text. This allows someone to change their mind before locking in their click. P1R3 needs to do the same and check if the text on P1R2 is a X or 2. If a 2, it changes the text to -. P1R4 is similar but checks P1R2 and P1R3 if the text is a X or a number.

Comment: I'm sorry, that didn't make it any better. Can you explain what button `P1R{n}` does, using that notation? Can you use `P1R{n-3...n-1}` to refer to a range? Are you following me?

Comment: P1Rn needs to check P1Rn-1, P1Rn-2, etc until the beginning of the array. Each button will need to run a check.

Comment: I'm struggling to get you to explain your logic in enough detail. Please read [ask]. Please provide excruciating detail.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than work with distinct variables, I suggest you create arrays of your buttons and check variables and then use those arrays.

Start with this:

```
private Button[] P1Buttons;
private bool[] P1ButtonsClicked;
```

Now, in `Form_Load` have this code:

```
P1Buttons = new []
{
    P1R2, P1R3, P1R4, P1R5, P1R6, P1R7,
    P1R8, P1R9, P1R10, P1R11, P1R12, 
};

P1ButtonsClicked = P1Buttons.Select(b => false).ToArray();

Array.ForEach(P1Buttons, b => b.Click += P1Button_Click);
```

You're attaching all of the `Click` events to this method:

```
private void P1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(P1Buttons, sender);
    if (P1ButtonsClicked[index] == false)
    {
        P1Buttons[index].Text = "X";
        P1ButtonsClicked[index] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        P1Buttons[index].Text = "2";
        P1ButtonsClicked[index] = false;
    }
}
```

You just need to now rewrite that code to handle all of the cases from `index == 0` (button `P1R2`) to `index == 10` (button `P1R12`).

I'd suggest that you do change your thinking on how you write that event handler a bit too. Try this:

```
private void P1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(P1Buttons, sender);
    P1Buttons[index].Text = P1ButtonsClicked[index] ? "2" : "X";
    P1ButtonsClicked[index] = !P1ButtonsClicked[index];
}
```

Eliminating `if` statements is usually a good way to reduce repetition and bugs.

Comment: Using your example from the bottom, if I were to use `P1Buttons[index].Text = P1ButtonsClicked[index] ? index.ToString() : "X";` should take care of the number portion, correct? I would still have to sort out changing the previous buttons to "-" instead, but this is a great start. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't cotton on to the idea that the "2" was the button number.